# Consistent Seg Fault at 2850800 blocks

Tags: monerod, synchronization

I'm attempting to sync the monero blockchain using the `monerod` CLI on my M2 MacBook. However, every time the sync reaches 96% complete (2850800 blocks), the process errors with a segmentation fault. Every time I restart the daemon, it exits immediately with the same error. After running `monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 800` and restarting the daemon, it starts syncing again, but once again hits a seg fault at 2850800. I have deleted the blockchain data twice now and restarted the daemon, first with the `--db-sync-mode safe` flag, and again with that flag and the `--prune-blockchain` flag, but neither seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the same issue as described in this GitHub issue: [issues/8657](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/8657).

If you installed Monero via homebrew (or another third party package manager) you will likely be building / installing a version that uses a version of the macOS SDK that appears to have an issue with the RandomX JIT (as detailed in [issues/8829](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/8829)).

The simplest solution is to use an official release from [getmonero.org/downloads](https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/). These are *reproducible* builds that use specific versions of all dependencies (including which macOS SDK to use). Alternatively build from source with `make depends target=x86_64-apple-darwin11` or use an environment variable `MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK=8` when starting.

Comment: Thanks, using the MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK override worked, though the syncing is now a bit slow. Do you think it'd be substantially faster if I just went ahead and used the older SDK?

Comment: It probably would be since the older release contains a working RandomX JIT which is more efficient (and faster) than interpreting RandomX.

Comment: Confirmed, the downloaded executable was substantially faster

Comment: The issue is the Mac SDK version, not the Monero version. Suggest updating the answer so users don't go downloading and installing earlier Monero versions.

Comment: The problem is solved by using the latest version from getmonero.org. Is there a different solution that doesn't require using an older release?
Feel free to suggest an edit to my answer or create an answer yourself.

Comment: "is solved by using the latest version" "Is there a different solution that doesn't require using an older release": the solution in this case is not to use an older version but use the *latest* binary release.