# zsh: segfault when trying to sync stagenet

Tags: monerod, macos, stagenet

I'm trying to sync a full node for stagenet using the monerod CLI tool on macOS 13.6.

It syncs for some time but then it randomly segfaults and I'm not sure why. The error message is as follows:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  monerod --stagenet --data-dir /Volumes/Crucial\ X6/monero_dev/
```

I've tried starting the sync again from scratch but it still segfaults. Are there any hidden files on the system somewhere I should get rid of to start a "clean" attempt?

I installed the Monero CLI tools from homebrew. I'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thank you.

Comment: Likely same as this Q/A: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/14035/7493

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it I think.